# Set comment toggle to false, error: There's no line here to end

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox, todonotes

I want to show/hide comments when toggeling the code below:

```
\newtoggle{comments}
%\toggletrue{comments}
\settoggle{comments}{true} %set true to show all comments, set false to hide all comments
\newcommand{\notemp}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=yellow]{{[}CORR.:{]} #1}{}}\linebreak}
```

My problem is that when I set `\settoggle{comments}{false}`, I get the error in my document:

```
./chapters/chapter01/chap01.tex:106: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.106 T
       this is a test comment...
```

Any suggestions, how to fix this error, but do not break the comments?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I took `\linebreak` out and received the following error:

```
./chapters/chapter02/chap02.tex:786: Undefined control sequence.
\endtcolorbox ->\unskip \tcb@after@box 
                                       \end {tcb@savebox}\tcb@draw@color@box...
l.786 \end{tcolorbox}
```

I am also using in my lated document the structures:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=orange,colframe=black,enhanced jigsaw, arc=3mm,boxsep=4pt,boxrule=0.5pt,breakable]
\textbf{Notes:}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Any suggestions, how to fix this error and toggle the comments with out?

Comment: the error is from `\linebreak` which you need to put in the conditional section just if you have text, as is you always do `\linebreak` so get an error that there is no line if you have not added any text before it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please have a look at my updated answer!

Comment: It is impossible to debug code that you can not see.  Please always make a small (few line) _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem, so people can reproduce it locally. Also that should be a _new_ question. whatever it is,  it is an unrelated problem unconnected to the question title.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I will close the question above and provide a new question.

Comment: For the interested ones: Here's the new question (and it's been solved, in my opinion) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269501/set-comment-toggle-to-false-error-undefined-control-sequence

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thx for interlinking!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been reposted at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269501/set-comment-toggle-to-false-error-undefined-control-sequence