# Set comment toggle to false, error: Undefined control sequence

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox, todonotes

I want to toggle comments of and on. Off works, but when I set toggle to true, then I get an error:

```
./main.tex:36: Undefined control sequence.
\endtcolorbox ->\unskip \tcb@after@box 
                                       \end {tcb@savebox}\tcb@draw@color@box...
l.36 \end{tcolorbox}
```

Here is an example document to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{tikz}                       
\usepackage{todonotes}                  
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}            
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,
               automata,backgrounds,
               petri,topaths}               %To use diverse features from tikz  
\usepackage{etoolbox}               

%create comment for me
\newtoggle{comments}
%\toggletrue{comments}
\settoggle{comments}{true} %set true to show all comments, set false to hide all comments
\newcommand{\notemp}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=yellow]{{[}MP{]} #1}{}}}
\newcommand{\notecorr}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}{}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text


\begin{document}
\notemp{this is one comment}

\lipsum

\notemp{this is one comment}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=orange,colframe=black,enhanced jigsaw, arc=3mm,boxsep=4pt,boxrule=0.5pt,breakable]
\textbf{Notes:}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item test item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\notecorr{this is another comment}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions, how to fix this error?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: Kare: Your toggle false branch is missing, that's why `tcolorbox` ends prematurely, giving the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of `\iftoggle` is

`\iftoggle{togglevariable}{true branch}{false branch}`

The macros

```
\newcommand{\notemp}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=yellow]{{[}MP{]} #1}{}}}
\newcommand{\notecorr}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}{}}}
```

close the true branch 'correctly', but there's no `{false}` branch, since
`#1}{}}` should be `#1}}{}` actually -- the first `}` ends the `\todo` argument, the 2nd one ends the true branch of `\iftoggle`, the (empty) false branch `{}` will follow!

To keep track of the `{}` pairs it's better (in my point of view) to write the toggle parts in different lines:

```
\iftoggle{togglevariable}{%
    code for true branch}{%
    code for false branch%
  }% end of false branch and `\iftoggle`
```

This simplifies error searching.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{tikz}                       
\usepackage{todonotes}                  
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}            
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,
               automata,backgrounds,
               petri,topaths}               %To use diverse features from tikz  
\usepackage{etoolbox}               

%create comment for me
\newtoggle{comments}
%\toggletrue{comments}
\settoggle{comments}{true} %set true to show all comments, set false to hide all comments
\newcommand{\notemp}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{comments}{%
    \todo[color=yellow]{{[}MP{]} #1}}{% false
  }%
}
\newcommand{\notecorr}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{comments}{%
    \todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}}{% false
  }%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text


\begin{document}
\notemp{this is one comment}

\lipsum

\notemp{this is one comment}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=orange,colframe=black,enhanced jigsaw, arc=3mm,boxsep=4pt,boxrule=0.5pt,breakable]
\textbf{Notes:}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item test item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\notecorr{this is another comment}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The braces are mixed up in your definition of `\notemp`: what you should do is

```
\newcommand{\notemps}[1]{
  \iftoggle{comments}{
    % when the toggle is on
    \todo[color=yellow]{{[}MP{]} #1}
  }{ % else
    {}
  }
}
```

Instead, you closed the braces like this:

```
\newcommand{\notemps}[1]{
  \iftoggle{comments}{
    % when the toggle is on
    \todo[color=yellow]{{[}MP{]} #1}
    {}
  }
}
```

Thus, the second argument to `\iftoggle` is taken from whatever you have next, and that's why it had an error in the `tcolorbox`.

Here are the fixed definitions.

```
\newcommand{\notemp}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=yellow]{{[}MP{]} #1}}{}}
\newcommand{\notecorr}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=green]{{[}COR.{]} #1}}{}}
```